# Prevented site from opening window

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, popup

[image]My wedsite getting "Prevented site from opening window." after deployment.

There is no much tricky code in that.

```
 if( $('#textbox').val().length == 0 ) {
alert("please fill the details");
}
```

While showing the alert I am getting the above alert. When I click on Allow its working fine .

Happening only in `IE and firefox`.

Please help. Really annoying. And in development mode its not coming. After deploy on tomcat getting this.

Comment: It is browser setting.  You are opening a popup window in your site and browser has blocked that.

Comment: WHAT and HOW are you opening new windows ? are you redirecting user to a new link in a new tab ? Or on the load of the main site itself you are getting this message, and how is the above alert box code related to this problem ?

Comment: Are you really sure it's the alert box that's triggering the message...?

Comment: Other than that no alerts in that page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a setting in your browser. In development it didn't happen because you were probably running it locally. Try disabling your popup blocker or adding your domain to the allow list

Comment: No .its happening to all browsers who ever accsing it.

Comment: Yes, it is an ubiquitous browser setting.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an alert box to warn a user that they haven't filled in a form correctly. There's all sorts of reasons why you don't want to do this. One of them is that the browser may prevent the page from doing so. The other reasons all have to do with how annoying this behaviour is to the user.

The user may have their speakers turned up so high that your alert box deafens them. They may happen to click on something as the alert box shows, causing them to lose the alert box on their desktop and preventing them from navigating your site. More than ever though, you are probably going to annoy your user - the browser is doing you a favour by blocking the alert box!

If the form has been filled in incorrectly, show an HTML element with a red background that will warn them. This achieves what you want without making noise or forcing the user to find something and click on it. Everyone's a winner!

Comment: I am not even submitting the form..based on the value enter in the text box ..am showing other controls .for form validations i am using validate.js..which is working fine.

Comment: whether or not you are submitting the form is irrelevant. Someone is trying to fill in the form and your alert box will hinder their efforts rather than help - even if the browser didn't block your alert box, it would still be better practice to display a prominent HTML element when the user enters an invalid value. You can use the same script, just trigger a different event.